# SendBulkMailRequest Class

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, workflow

I'm writing custom workflow in Dynamics CRM. Has anybody used `SendBulkMailRequest` Class? This class we used for sending bulk mail to the contacts and the scenario is like, sending a bulk mail and later update the field in other entity for every successful mails sent.

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj602919.aspx) is the reference link of the class. Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What’s your question? Have you tried & facing issues?

Comment: Thank you @ArunVinoth.  I tried the code, The bulk mails are going fine.  The issue is, for every successful mail sent, I want to update a field in another entity. 
we have a field called (IsMailSent-->bool) in opportunity entity. I want to update this fields to true if the mail is sent success, Otherwise it should be false. 


SendBulkMailResponse resp = (SendBulkMailResponse)
                        _serviceProxy.Execute(bulkMailRequest);


This code send mails to all contacts. How can I update that flag for successful mail sent records.

Answer (score 0):

You are sending Bulk Emails to Contacts, then you are tracking the Email sent flag in Opportunity record. I assume you are having a way to find out the right opportunity to update from the contact in Email recipient. (Just curious - What are you setting as regarding of those Emails?)

**My recommendation**: Register a plugin on Email create, then retrieve the contact's opportunity, set the flag `IsMailSent` to true & do a `Service.Update(Oppty)`

I guess `SendBulkMailRequest` message is just like broadcaster, as I noticed the below comments inside [code sample](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj602919.aspx).

> // When the bulk email operation has completed, all sent emails will
>   // have a status of "Pending Send" and will be picked up by your email
>   // router.  Alternatively, you can then use BackgroundSendEmail to download
>   // all the emails created with the SendBulkEmail message.
>   // See the BackgroundSendEmail sample for an example.